# Возврат суммы значений в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть массив `query`:

```
[{"item_count":"2"},{"item_count":"11"},{"item_count":"13"}]
```

Необходимо вернуть сумму значений `item_count`.

Моя попытка:

```
for (val in query)
{
   val = val.item_count;
   val = val++;
}

Response.Write(val);
```

Выводит 14, не понимаю, почему.

Comment: Потому что перезапись значений и результат конечное 13 и увеличение его на единицу )

Comment: если это яваскрипт, вообще странно как 14 получается

Answer (score 0):

```
for (val in query)
{  // Давайте представим, что это последняя итерация, у нас есть какое то значение val.
   val = val.item_count; // Тут мы туда записываем (не приплюсовываем) значение из последнего элемента массива
   val = val++; // Добавляем туда 1
}
// тут val = последний элемент массива + 1

Response.Write(val);
```

```js
const query = [{"item_count":"2"},{"item_count":"11"},{"item_count":"13"}];
const val = query.reduce((sum, item) => sum + +item.item_count, 0);
console.log(val);
```

Comment: если учесть, что `query` - это массив, то `for..in`, бежит по индексам массива, индекс - это число, у числа нет свойства `item_count`, следовательно на второй строке значение у val будет undefined, применив `++` к undefied получим `NaN`, как автор получает какое-то число - решительно непонятно

Comment: @Grundy горбатого лепишь, тут довольно очевидно как он получил 14

Comment: Неочевидно, код который он предоставил - вернет `NaN`. Если он получает что-то еще - значит у него другой код. Просто добавь его код в сниппет - и посмотри как он возвращает 14 :-)

Comment: @Darth вообще ни разу не очевидно по коду из вопроса. Во-первых, учитывая что `val` - индекс, то дело кончится `NaN`-ом. Во-вторых, даже если бы было `for (val of query)`, то выводилось бы `13`, а не `14`.

Comment: Если у вас есть более лучшие идеи, как ТС получил 14 - озвучьте